# Spark java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

[Spark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Spark) is throwing `ClassCastExpection` when performing any operation on WrappedArray.

Example:

I have an map output like below

**Output:**

```
Map(1 -> WrappedArray(Pan4), 2 -> WrappedArray(Pan15), 3 -> WrappedArray(Pan16, Pan17, Pan18), 4 -> WrappedArray(Pan19, Pan1, Pan2, Pan3, Pan4, Pan5, Pan6))]
```

when invoked map.values, it's printing the output as the below output

```
MapLike(WrappedArray(Pan4), WrappedArray(Pan15), WrappedArray(Pan16, Pan17, Pan18), WrappedArray(Pan19, Pan1, Pan2, Pan3, Pan4, Pan5, Pan6))
```

It is throwing the exception if invoked by `map.values.map(arr => arr)` or `map.values.forEach { value => println(value)}`.

I am not able to perform any operation on the wrapped array. I just need the size of the elements present in each wrappedArray.

```
Error StackTrace
------------------
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList
    at WindowTest$CustomMedian$$anonfun$1.apply(WindowTest.scala:176)
    at WindowTest$CustomMedian$$anonfun$1.apply(WindowTest.scala:176)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map4.foreach(Map.scala:181)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at WindowTest$CustomMedian.evaluate(WindowTest.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ScalaUDAF.eval(udaf.scala:446)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.AggregationIterator$$anonfun$35.apply(AggregationIterator.scala:376)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.AggregationIterator$$anonfun$35.apply(AggregationIterator.scala:368)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.SortBasedAggregationIterator.next(SortBasedAggregationIterator.scala:154)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.SortBasedAggregationIterator.next(SortBasedAggregationIterator.scala:29)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$14.hasNext(Iterator.scala:389)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:308)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:212)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1858)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:227)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Please provide your sample code that you are using!

Comment: @ShivanshSrivastava resolved the error by changing it to Sequence type...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I resolved the error by converting to `Seq` (sequence type).

Earlier:

```
val bufferMap: Map[Int, util.ArrayList[String]] = buffer.getAs[Map[Int, util.ArrayList[String]]](1)
```

Modified:

```
val bufferMap: Map[Int, Seq[String]] = buffer.getAs[Map[Int, Seq[String]]](1)
```

Answer (score 2):

For those using Java Spark, encode the data set into an object instead of using `Row` and then the `getAs` method.

Suppose this data set that has some random information about a machine:

```
+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+---------+--------------------+
|epoch      |     RValues|     SValues|    TValues|      ids|               codes|
+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+---------+--------------------+
| 1546297225| [-1.0, 5.0]|  [2.0, 6.0]| [3.0, 7.0]|   [2, 3]|[MRT0000020611, M...|
| 1546297226| [-1.0, 3.0]| [-6.0, 6.0]| [3.0, 4.0]|   [2, 3]|[MRT0000020611, M...|
| 1546297227| [-1.0, 4.0]|[-8.0, 10.0]| [3.0, 6.0]|   [2, 3]|[MRT0000020611, M...|
| 1546297228| [-1.0, 6.0]|[-8.0, 11.0]| [3.0, 5.0]|   [2, 3]|[MRT0000020611, M...|
+-----------+------------+------------+-----------+---------+--------------------+
```

Instead of having `Dataset<Row>`, create `Dataset<MachineLog>` that complies with this dataset column definition and create the `MachineLog` class. When doing a transformation, use the `.as(Encoders.bean(MachineLog.class))` method to define the encoder.

For example:

```
spark.createDataset(dataset.rdd(), Encoders.bean(MachineLog.class));
```

But converting from a `Dataset` to `RDD` is not recommended. Try to use the `as` method.

```
Dataset<MachineLog> mLog = spark.read().parquet("...").as(Encoders.bean(MachineLog.class));
```

It can also be used after a transformation.

```
Dataset<MachineLog> machineLogDataset = aDataset
                .join(
                        otherDataset,
                        functions.col("...").eqNullSafe("...")
                        )
                ).as(Encoders.bean(MachineLog.class));
```

Take into account that `MachineLog` class must obey the *serialization* rules (i.e., having anempty-explicit constructor, and getters and setters).

Answer (score 1):

Try the below

```
map.values.**array**.forEach { value => println(value)}
```

*array* is a method in `WrapperArray`. It returns `Array[T]`. Here T is the type of the elements in the `WrappedArray`.

Comment: Doesn't work... It throws java.lang.ArrayStoreException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef
 at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.array_update(ScalaRunTime.scala:88)